# docker image profiling for different platforms

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

Using Gitlab CI ,

Can I create 2 images with minor different requirements from the same Docker File?

the output image name will be different based on the difference as well.

lets call it volumes difference

One image type will include volumes for exposing of data to host
2nd image type will have files embedded inside them instead of mounting volumes

requirement is to use same project/branch in Gitlab CI and no more code duplicates for the sake of 2 outcomes.

Comment: For the example that you’ve given, you can use the same image for both: `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile mostly only has confusing side effects and doesn’t affect your ability to mount a volume in any particular directory.  Also note that the direction of volume mounts is pushing data _into_ a container and not exposing data out of it.

Comment: volumes were just for example -- actually its a complete new image for a different platform -- complexity is to use only 1 single branch code and develop 2 different images.